# Referencing an element within a has()?

Tags: jquery

If you have the following code:

```
 $('.object').has('span').each(function () {
    $(this).// do things to each match....
});
```

Is there an easy way to target the span of $(this)?

Something like

```
$(this + 'span').//do things to span of current element
```

I am almost sure it is very easy to do, but I tried researching this on Google but the terms are so generic I'm struggling to find any reference!

Comment: have you tried this on jQuery?

Comment: You can give a concrete example with some html, easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> target the span of $(this)?

You can use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to select the descendant elements with that selector:

```
$(this).find("span")
// or
$("span", this)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.object').has('span').each(function() {
    $("span", this)..
});
```